# Set cookie with HTTP request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I want to save an id in a cookie that is specific for a HTTP request to the server. So I want the cookie to be set just before the HTTP request is send so that there is no chance that another browser tab overwrites this value before the HTTP request is sent.

Is the jquery unload() function the best practice to accomplish this?
Something like this:

```
$(window).unload(function() {
  $.removeCookie("Test_Cookie");
  $.cookie("Test_Cookie", "test");
});
```

Comment: Did you try it?  Does it result in the cookie being set?  What is triggering the request to the server?

Comment: When what http request is sent? If you are talking about ajax need more details

Comment: My solution only works when it navigates away from the page. I have an ASP.NET MVC application and want the cookie to be set every time before an action method in any of the controller is called.